# reloading media folder in wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm trying to add images to the the cms. I can see how do do it through the cms. Is it possible to add them just by adding them to the media directory and reloading them. It would make it easier to manage as I could use the shell to move things around.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. Wagtail needs to keep a database entry for each image, so having them on the file system is not enough.

Comment: I assumed that you could load images to the cms by adding them to the cms media directory and then running something to make the database consistant with that directory.